# Why won't my upgrade button work more than once?

Tags: html

so I'm currently making a clicker game With a twist that the only thing that makes you bottles are bottlers, but they are directly upgraded along with the bottle type throughout the game until you can beat it, and here is my code so far. if you run the code you can see that pressing the upgrade button more than once only returns an error, how do I fix this? also if anyone has any tips to improve or shorten the code I'll take that as well as this is my first time coding.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="bottle1.png">
  <title>Bottle empire</title>
  <style>
    p.cash {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
      position: relative;
      left: -5px;
    }

    p.cookie {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
      position: relative;
      top: -300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<center>
  <p class="cash">Cash: <span id="score">0</span></p>
</center>
<center><img src="bottle1.png" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(1)"></center>


<Center><button onclick="upgrade()">Upgrade bottle [<span id="upgradecost">1000</span>] </button></Center>


<button onclick="buybottler()">Bottler [<span id="bottlercost">10</span>] -- <span id="bottlers">0</span></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/3.0.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var score = 1000000;

  var bottlercost = 10;
  var bottlers = 0;
  var upgradecost = 1000;

  function buybottler() {
    if (score >= bottlercost) {
      score = score - bottlercost;
      bottlers = bottlers + 1;
      bottlercost = Math.round(bottlercost * 1.15);

      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
      document.getElementById("bottlercost").innerHTML = bottlercost;
      document.getElementById("bottlers").innerHTML = bottlers;
      document.getElementById("upgradecost").innerHTML = upgradecost
      
    }
  }

  
   function upgrade() {
    if (score >= upgradecost) {
      score = score - upgradecost;
      upgrade = upgrade + 1;
      upgradecost = upgradecost * 5;

      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
      document.getElementById("upgradecost").innerHTML = upgradecost
      
    }
  }

  function addToScore(amount) {
    score = score + amount
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  }

  setInterval(function () {
    score = score + bottlers
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  }, 2000); // 2000 msec = 1 sec


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the `<center>` tag was deprecated around 1997 and you shouldn’t use it. And there are 1000 ms in a second.

Comment: @rayhatfield Even worse, the `<center>` element was marked [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) at least 15 years ago.

Comment: well then what am i supposed to put to center it?

Answer (score 3):

You're reassigning the value of `upgrade` in the `upgrade` function itself (therefore essentially removing your `upgrade()` function)

```js
function upgrade() {
  if (score >= upgradecost) {
    score = score - upgradecost;
    upgrade = upgrade + 1; // Here
    ...
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this line, but removing it will fix your error problem

Comment: To clarify: after this runs, `upgrade` isn’t your function anymore. It’s whatever your function plus one is—due to the way type coercion works in js it’ll be a string. So attempting to invoke it as a function again will throw an error.

Comment: Renamed the function and it works now. Thanks for explaining the error to me.